# How to do circular loop CurvedChildLayoutManager for wear android?

Tags: java, android, rounding, wear-os

I need to repeat item with data when in up and down with array of three elements.

...
item 1
item 2
item 3
item 1
item 2
item 3
...

Answer (score 0):

You should do it the same way you would with any `LayoutManager` and `RecyclerView`.

So in short, modify your `RecyclerView.Adapter`:

1. Make `getItemCount` return `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.
2. When getting your item use `list.get(position % list.size)` instead of `list.get(position)`
3. Move to the middle position `layoutManager.scrollToPosition((int)(Integer.MAX_VALUE/2f))` after you initialize your `RecyclerView` (you might need to add an `int` to the `Integer.MAX_VALUE/2f` depending on your dataset and your choice on which item should be displayed first).

This way you will not repeat your data set and still maintain the illusion of inifinite scrolling.

Comment: But I need add this line "wearableRecyclerView .setCenterEdgeItems(true);" and with this line it is not work.

Comment: it is not scroll to center list with this setCenterEdgeItems(true)
but if i  disabled this line it is work

Comment: or how I can move item  selected to center screen ?